# Does P=NP imply polynomial solutions to #P?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time

Is it true that $\#P$-complete problems could possibly be solved in polynomial time if P=NP? I know that even some counting problems related to polynomial time decision problems are $\#P$-complete, so even if P=NP it may not necessarily be true.  My confusion is over how we write the answer to a $\#P$-complete problem since it may be exponential in the size of the input (for example up to $2^n$ truth assignments to a SAT instance on $n$ variables).  Therefore, I cannot understand how, even if we find a fast way for computing something like the permanent of a matrix, we could still expect to write the answer in polynomial time. Am I missing something about the definition of $\#P$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your confusion is that the class **#P** only asks you to *count* the solutions, not to enumerate them, and you only need $n$ bits to write down the number $2^n$. This means that to express the number of satisfying assignments to a formula of $n$ variables, you need $n$ bits, because there are at most $2^n$ solutions (i.e. in the case of a tautology). Another example: the number of isomorphisms between two graphs is at most $n!$, which requires $\log(n!)\approx n\cdot \log(n)$ bits to write down. All these number of bits are polynomial in the size of the input

**#P** can be solved in polynomial time if and only if **P=PP**. This is a stronger statement than **P=NP**, because **P=PP** implies **P=NP** (and hence, it is less likely). If **P=NP**, then all **#P** problems can be approximated to within a constant factor by a deterministic algorithm.

Comment: So what about if just P = NP, without knowing if P = PSpace? Would that imply #P problems can be solved in polynomial time?

Comment: @Parry Good question. I looked it up in Arora and Barak's *Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach*, and updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**P$\,=\,$NP** does not imply that **P$\,=\,$#P** (or, more properly, **FP$\,=\,$#P**). We already know that there are decision problems in **P** whose counting versions are **#P**-complete, such as perfect matchings.